# Casting fails on subquery result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cast

I'm in a bit of a pickle, I have to perform a query on a database with rather poor data quality. I am trying to evaluate a field which contains a date, but which was defined as a `nvarchar`. I thought I would be able to cast the value to an integer but this fails as there also non-date values in the date field (random letters and signs,etc...).

What I decided to do is as follows:

```
SELECT q.foo, cast( q.bar as int) 
FROM ( SELECT foo,bar FROM table where ISNUMERIC(bar) = 1) as q 
WHERE q.bar > 20140401
```

But this still crashes stating conversion failed on the nvarchar value `'.       '`. I expected that all values would  be castable to int as they were numeric?

Comment: BOL states **ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-)** so I would imagine this is possibly the issue you are seeing

Comment: And there's a good answer to this on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400318/why-does-isnumeric-return-1). If you're on 2012, use TRYPARSE or TRYCONVERT

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on 2008 :(

Comment: Ok then, create your own [helper function](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber/)?

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap a CASE inside the CAST(), so the CAST() is only performed on valid numeric values - the other ones will result in NULL unless you put an ELSE in there somewhere.

Also, your conversion error probably stems from the WHERE clause, where q.bar is implicitly converted to int in order to compare it to 20140401 (which is an int).

This will probably solve your problem:

```
SELECT q.foo, CAST((CASE WHEN q.bar NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN q.bar END) AS int) 
FROM ( SELECT foo,bar FROM table) as q 
WHERE q.bar > '20140401';
```

Comment: Great to see the correct *all-digits* test used in place of the inadequate ISNUMERIC() function.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a date table the following could work. If the date table does not already have a column for the date format stored in table.bar then create the column or cast.

```
select t.foo, t.bar
from table t
join date_table dt on t.bar like '%' + dt.DateID +'%'
where dt.DateID > 20140401
```

Since you would be using a date table it would probably be better to write the query like this.

```
select t.foo, dt.date_column as [bar]
from table t
join date_table dt on t.bar like '%' + dt.DateID +'%'
where dt.date_column > '20140401'
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `isdate` a try.  Here is the test I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (Id int not null identity(1,1), stringdate varchar(30))

INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('1/1/2014'),('abc'),('01012014'),('1114'),('20140101')

SELECT stringdate, CASE WHEN ISDATE(stringdate) = 1 THEN cast(stringdate as datetime) END
FROM Foo 
WHERE ISDATE(stringdate) = 1
```

This only returned entries for '1/1/2014' and '20140101' because they were the only ones I could validly convert to a date. Note: The behavior of `isdate` will depend on certain settings on your server. `SET LANGUAGE` for example but should handle the problems you are having.

Link to BOL for `isdate`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: My understanding is that a subquery is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause.  I'll find a work around.

Comment: @PaulWhite Added a `CASE` to the `SELECT` clause and removed the subquery since it's unnecessary and just adds complication to query.  I did keep the `ISDATE` in the `WHERE` clause so only valid results will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

In which format are the date values stored?

If you can determine the used format you can [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with the specified format by resticting the rows using [LEN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [LIKE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) predicate.

Example:
If you have the date values stored like '10/23/2016' you can use U.S. standard (101)

```
 SELECT [foo], CONVERT(DATETIME, [bar], 101)
 FROM [table]
 WHERE LEN([bar]) = 10 AND [bar] LIKE '[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: This assumes the `WHERE` clause is applied before the expression in the `SELECT` clause is evaluated, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: Also this allows "dates" like `'19/39/9765'`.

Comment: @PaulWhite For my own curiosity: Is it guaranteed if the `WHERE` is moved to a sub-query/CTE?

Comment: @ckerth No it is not.